# Nullable Type in ATL COM

Tags: com, nullable, atl

I am working on the data access in C++ ATL/COM.
How do you pass a nullable type (e.g. nullable integer) in an interface???

Comment: Seems that we need to use variant_t (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987261/c-sharp-good-way-to-expose-nullablet-to-com?rq=1)... In other words my entity will be full of variants... which can be a pain. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ATL/C++ in in interfaces (IDL) you don't have nullable classes and support in language constructs (`<type>?` in C#). Nullable is basically the type itself and an extra `BOOL` indicating whether we currently have `NULL` or not.

One can implement a relatively simple template class to look - to extend possible - similarly to C# [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx). On the interface this will be either two arguments, or as you discovered you can use `VARIANT` type since it already embeds payload value and `.vt` member indicating type. `VT_NULL` constant is what it says for itslef - the value of the whole variant is null.

Comment: I'm accessing database within the component and therefore I believe using variant is probably the best option (since ADO itself uses it).